# How can I get access token from the users logged in with Google/Apple account from mobile device?

Tags: laravel

I made a mobile app using Flutter, and I was able to login via Google and Apple account. But my Laravel backend uses access token provided by Laravel Passport so I can't fetch without that access token and signing in the user using both of them does not register them in my backed.

I have googled for few hours, and ask for help on several communities. So far, I have this sort of flow from their inputs:

1. Let the user sign in using those platform
2. Once successful, register them manually on the backend as new user with data pulled from them
3. Create an access token based on that user
4. Authenticate all API request with that access token.

The problem is, registering the user with that method requires the password field to be nullable since I have no access to their password anyways, which can leads to security issues and storing random password for them will confuse the user when they want to login using email for some reason after they are registered from those platform.

The Laravel app is just an API, and has no website access (yet). So how do I suppose to let Laravel knows that a new user is signed in using Google/Apple account in secure (perhaps, the proper) way? And how can I get the access token from it?

Comment: Are you using https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite ?

Comment: no, i only use laravel passport

Comment: Can you show us some code?